# How does one search through 10 Billion records?

Tags: database, performance, record

This is not a problem i'm having, just a question i've always wondered. Asking it here to improve myself with knowledge.

So i have basic database knowledge mysql, queries etc.

But looking at sites like haveibeenpwned. They claim that they have around 10 Billion records. Giving them your email they will query and search through their database to find your email.

In less than 1 second they provide a result with all breaches your email is found in.

My question is, how is this done? Can MySQL handle this? Can this be achieved by indexing text files with a special algoritm?

Comment: This is likely **too broad a question** for Stack Overflow. This site is designed to avoid long-winded or open-ended discussions. I suggest you use a forums site such as http://www.CodeRanch.com/

Answer (score 1):

I've personally worked with 500 million rows in MySQL, a big database for MySQL standard, but still 20 times short of the 10 billion rows you mention.

I don't know how well MySQL fares with 10 billion rows but with today's hardware it should be decent at least.

Now, about the search:

- A search inside a database of this magnitude must use an index.
- Must have a very narrow filtering criteria. You probably need to narrow your criteria into the low thousands of rows of data at most.
- Must use "Index Seek" operations or "Index Range Scan" on a very limited range of rows.
- Search/Primary tables (where indexes are) must have a limited number of lightweight columns, to minimize the size of the table and their indexes.
- Additional heavy data (images, documents, audio, video, long texts, etc.) must be stored in separate tables that can be looked up when the search has been narrowed down on the primary tables.

If you do that, your search queries can run fast, real fast, even on such big databases. In any case, you'll need to tailor the specific structures of the data to ensure a great speed.